# Do not get mod_rewrite working with $_GET['page']

Tags: php, .htaccess

My current link is:

```
domain.com/folder/index.php?page=home
```

and i try to get it to this:

```
domain.com/folder/home
```

The PHP code that I use to get the page

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
$page = $_GET['page'];
} else {
$page = 'home';
}
if (strpos($page, '/') !== false || !file_exists("pages/$page.php")) {
$page = 'error';
}
include ("pages/$page.php");
?>
```

I tryed a lot to get the right .htaccess code to rewrite my URL, from generators to forum posts but I can not get the right code.

I hope someone can get me in the right direction to get this working.

Comment: I suggest you post your http host configuration and the contents of your `.htaccess` style file, so that we can help. We are not really interested in that php based router you posted...

Comment: Post your htaccess. We can't really help without it.

Comment: "My current link is" - you need to change these links in your application, if you haven't already.

Answer (score 4):

these `.htaccess` rules should help you get started

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#### this allows you to write your links in the form /folder/home ####
RewriteRule ^folder/([0-9]+)$ folder/index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]


#### to dynamically redirect to /folder/home ####
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index\.php)?\?page=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Redirect ^(.*).php$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

utilize this in your htaccess

Comment: **No** ! Query strings can not be handled in Redirect directive.

Comment: Note that Rediret directive doesnt support regex, Your edied code will cause redirect loop error on the server if used with RedirectMatch that supports regex . A better way to solve the OP's problem is mod_rewrite.